# UIRefresh Control UI bug with large titles & collection view

Tags: swift, uirefreshcontrol

I am using a UICollectionViewController embedded within a UITabBarController & UINavigationController and when I switch between tabs multiple times I am occasionally experiencing a bug where the refresh control appears above the title when I do not want it to.

[Refresh Control UI Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aOvn.png)

[Debug View Hierachy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt9Bq.png)

```
var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.primaryRed
    return refreshControl
}()

refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: .valueChanged)
collectionView?.refreshControl = refreshControl

@objc private func refreshData() {
    refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    datasource.fetchEvents {
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing collectionView?.refreshControl = refreshControl to collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl) and then check, don't forgot to add this line as well after adding refreshControl as a subview. collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

Comment: That caused worse UI issues :(

Comment: ok,, then make it hidden while adding. unhide it before this line refreshControl.beginRefreshing() and hide it again after reloadData.

Comment: I've tried this but for some reason it doesn't hide... I've also tried setting tint colour to clear but it seems to have issues updating itself

Comment: Comment refreshControl.beginRefreshing() this line and then check.

Comment: Tried. The isHidden property doesn't seem to be doing anything...

Comment: Bro just comment this line refreshControl.beginRefreshing() from your code and then check again.